# Change selected value of kendo ui dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

I have a [kendo ui dropdownlist](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/index.html) in my view:

```
$("#Instrument").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "symbol",
    dataValueField: "symbol",
    dataSource: data,
    index: 0
});
```

How can I change the selected value of it using jQuery?
I tried:

```
$("#Instrument").val(symbol);
```

But it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You have to use Kendo UI DropDownList `select` method (documentation in [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#methods-select)).

Basically you should:

```
// get a reference to the dropdown list
var dropdownlist = $("#Instrument").data("kendoDropDownList");
```

If you know the index you can use:

```
// selects by index
dropdownlist.select(1);
```

If not, use:

```
// selects item if its text is equal to "test" using predicate function
dropdownlist.select(function(dataItem) {
    return dataItem.symbol === "test";
});
```

JSFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/mRmNJ/)

Comment: selecting by index works fine but the second solution doesn't work. I tried alert(dataItem.text) in the function before return statement but it says undefined.

Comment: Sorry, I've already edited the answer, it should say `dataItem.symbol`. See JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/mRmNJ/

Comment: @anilca If you don't know the Index, you can also select by Text (dataItem.Text)

Comment: is it possible to use angularjs in updating the selected item?

Comment: Not work for me, when i tried to get the value after selecting by both methods, the value is null

Comment: If your KendoDropdown has a `change` event, you must trigger it manually by calling `dropdownlist.trigger("change");` after calling `select`.

Answer (score 33):

The Simplest way to do this is:

```
$("#Instrument").data('kendoDropDownList').value("A value");
```

Here is the [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gangwu6/vjc39eLL/2/).

Comment: I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" error in my project

Comment: @ÖmürBilgili You'll probably need to check for undefined first: `var inst = $("#Instrument").data('kendoDropDownList'); if (inst) { inst.value("A value"); }`

Answer (score 7):

Since this is one of the top search results for questions related to this I felt it was worth mentioning how you can make this work with Kendo().DropDownListFor() as well.

Everything is the same as with OnaBai's post except for how you select the item based off of its text and your selector.

To do that you would swap out dataItem.symbol for dataItem.[DataTextFieldName].  Whatever model field you used for .DataTextField() is what you will be comparing against.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.Status.StatusId)
    .Name("Status.StatusId")
    .DataTextField("StatusName")
    .DataValueField("StatusId")
    .BindTo(...)
)

//So that your ViewModel gets bound properly on the post, naming is a bit 
//different and as such you need to replace the periods with underscores
var ddl = $('#Status_StatusId').data('kendoDropDownList');    

ddl.select(function(dataItem) {
    return dataItem.StatusName === "Active";
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Seems there's an easier way, at least in Kendo UI v2015.2.624:

```
$('#myDropDownSelector').data('kendoDropDownList').search('Text value to find');
```

If there's not a match in the dropdown, Kendo appears to set the dropdown to an unselected value, which makes sense.

---

I couldn't get [@Gang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35437290/1028230) to work, but if you swap his `value` with `search`, as above, we're golden.

Comment: I made an example and it worked: http://jsfiddle.net/gangwu6/vjc39eLL/2/  I tried both .search('A value') and .value("A value") they both worked and I did not see any differences.

Comment: I can't get this to work when my ddl values have a comma in them. For example, if the drop down has "Horseface, USA" and I search for "USA" results in nothing being found.

Comment: @redwards510 I don't have an active Kendo project right now, but I iirc **you have to have an *exact* match for `search`**. Poorly named function, I'd agree. For your case, you'd need to write your own search routine using the raw `data`, find an exact match [again, through your own search routine], then select-via-`search`-function the exact match you've found. Sound good?

Comment: Yes, the not-so-obvious "search" works, thanks.

[And why would I have the index, as described previously on this page. I didn't implement Kendo, just using the widgets...]

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to "natively" select by value:

```
dropdownlist.select(1);
```

Comment: this doesn't work as expected with kendo.  It won't trigger events and therefore won't update the display.