# Kendo DropdownList Set Value From Model

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

Here is my Entity Edit Page Code,

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(x => x.ParentCategoryId).Name("ParentCategoryId").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px;" }).DataTextField("Name").Value("ID").DataValueField("ID")
                      .DataSource(source => { source.Read(read => { read.Action("GetCategory", "Category"); }); }))
```

and i want to set dropdownlist selected item by Model.ParentCategoryId

is it possible  dropdownlist.selectedvalue = Model.ParentCategoryId ?

Comment: yes you are right binding is well. But, in my editpview  i want to  select item in kendo dropdownlist by model.ParentCategoryId ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the selected item in the dropdown, you need to give the dropdown some information so it knows what item to select from its data binding.

A simple javascript approach might be:

```
var dropdownlist = $("#dropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList");

dropdownlist.select(function(dataItem) {
    return dataItem.text === "SomeStringToMatchUp";
});
```

In your case, you would use *.value* instead of *.text*. I don't really use your method, so you might actually have to set *dataItem.SomeName* for this approach to work.

If you want to set the default selection, one approach of several valid tactics is to set it after =
[databinding is complete (event)](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/dropdownlist#events-dataBound)

EDIT: [Here is another similar thread which you should reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106682/change-selected-value-of-kendo-ui-dropdownlist). Remember that search is your best friend!

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
        var dropdownlist = $("#KendoDDL").data("kendoDropDownList");
        dropdownlist.select(function (dataItem) {
            return dataItem.Name === "isim0";
        });
    });

i tried like this and didn't word :(

Comment: You might want to do some JS debugging and peek inside your DDL and var dropdownlist to see if it is populating correctly. Also make sure that your <Script> tag with the above function is located at the bottom of the page.