# Change Dropdown List Selected Value

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have tried doing it in jQuery :

```
var dropdownlist = $("#Instrument").data("kendoDropDownList");
dropdownlist.select(function(dataItem) {
    return dataItem.symbol === "test";
});
```

**Sources:** 
- http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/mRmNJ/
- [Change selected value of kendo ui dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106682/change-selected-value-of-kendo-ui-dropdownlist)

Is there a way to do this using AngularJS without directly accessing DOM?

Comment: Binding works differently in angular than it did in jquery.  Look into the ng-model directive.  It is used to bind things in angular.

Answer (score 1):

**Change Dropdown list selected value in Angularjs**

live code is :http://jsfiddle.net/RLQhh/992/

**controller.js**

```
app.controller('SelectController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.data = [
    { "symbol": "GOOG" }, 
    { "symbol": "AAPL" },
    { "symbol": "HPQ" },
    { "symbol": "CSCO" }
    ];

    $scope.label = '';
    $scope.change = function(){
    $scope.label =$scope.data[2].symbol;
    }

});
```

**HTML code is**

```
<div ng-controller="SelectController">
    <Button ng-click="change()" >Button</Button>
    <select class="form-control"  ng-model="label" ng-change="showTask()"   ng-options="d.symbol as d.symbol for d in data" >
                <option value="" disabled>Select Task</option>
                            </select>
</div>
```